# Do I use an Arduino or an ARM based Launchpad board for my commercial project?

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, arduino-ide, hardware, temperature-sensor

I want to use a board for an Industrial Project, which is based on temperature sensing, sharing and data storage.

Which board do I use?
Will it be reliable for a long span of time?
Will it be foolproof?

Comment: Neither: use a PIC32 based chipKIT board. But then that's just my opinion, just like every other answer you will get to such a question.

Comment: Microcontrollers are basically made to run "forever". But where/how are you sharing/storing data? Just sensing temperatur and sending it over RS485 (common in industry) can be achieved by making your own board, but you'll have to be sure that it can resist voltage spikes etc. Also your code has to be able to recognize and act upon errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Candice the Cyborg's answer above.
Which board do I use? 
Since its a commericial project you are going to sell then -I would say the right answer is the cheapest ARM or Arduino based board (when migrated to breadboard) to make your project. 
Will it be reliable for a long span of time? 
For reliability ARM and arduino would be reliable-they are after all both professional engineering products-and both can be used to make commercial products. I am assuming can be sure that your software for the ARM or Arduino is not buggy and professional-thus there is no reliability issues from the software. The span of time that the arduino can retain information reliably is given  in the data sheet-I think its about 100 years.
Will it be foolproof? 
Yes if you can be sure that you get the hardware design correct and the software correct-I would imagine this is where a problem would probably come from for your device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are want to be professional, make a custom PCB. This lets your project be neither and also stronger. This also makes you look like you actually spent more time on the project and make it great for industries.

If you still want to use an Arduino based board, you might as well use an Teensy 3.2. They are small, powerful and are still at a low price. Buy it [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13736).

If you make a good case for your project, it could last quite a long time. It might even last many years of continuous run outside at unregulated temperatures. Just make sure it doesn't get in contact with water or high levels of humidity and you should be good.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Seems quite reliable. I think I will make a custom PCB then. Now my question is, which processors do you think are reliable? ARM processors or the ATMega based ones?

Comment: A couple of sensors or a simple circuit will run fine with an ATmega. Want more power, a more reliable and fast processor use ARM. An ARM is better in everyway except the price and the simplicity.

Comment: All processors are reliable. It's the software that people write to run on them that isn't.